# How can you print a file using Win32 Printing and Print Spooler Functions

Tags: file, winapi, printing

I am trying to figure out how you can print a file, for example an excel spreadsheet using the Win32 Printing and Print Spooler Functions.  I know the path of the file, but don't have a clue to send it to the print spooler.

Answer (score 3):

You can call ShellExecute with lpOperation="print", see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx

Note this will only work for document types that have the print verb defined, right click on a document you want to print and see if Print appears in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

to print an excel file, you will have to use excel (or write your own excel file parser - ouch).  eg, via Automation. try googling: excel automation

Comment: I am speaking in the sense of programatically using the Win32 API (i.e. Printing and Printer Spooler Functions).

Comment: You will have to use the COM API for this.